# how to log out the user from mesibo in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mesibo

I am trying to implement chat feature in flutter using `mesibo_flutter_sdk 2.2.0` but if I call `setAccessToken` method with token of the user 1 then logout from the app and set the access token to token of the user 2 then the messages I send from user 1 are shown as if they were sent from user 2.
Also `.getSelfProfile()` is returning the profile of the previous user.
am I missing a way to log the user out from mesibo if so how do i do that?

I tried calling  `setAccessToken` with empty string to see if that logs out the user but it didn't work

Comment: Abrar, currently flutter does not have a logout api. I am raising an internal ticket for it.

Comment: Can you please reply here once the issue is resolved or if it has an estimated date on which it may get fixed? We are stuck because of this issue.

Comment: Absolutely. we will update here.

Comment: we are stuck on this problem @mesibo, any updates?